# 10S BMS board with three negative connections: -B, -P and -C

Tags: bms

I'm building a 4P10S Li-ion pack and have seen some diagrams that show no connection to -P and others that connect -P to "Discharging negative":

[image: BMS connection]

What is recommended and why?

Comment: Where else would you connect the plug "Discharge negative"?

Comment: What does the manual says how to connect it? If the product has no manual, maybe others are guessing and conneting things incorrectly or randomly.

Comment: @Justme, the problem is precisely the lack of a manual. A search over the internet returned at least two connection diagrams, and I am trying to decide which is better.

Comment: @PauloScheidegger Don't buy or use things without manuals. That's just a way for the seller to get rid of unknown junk boards without paying for scrapping them as waste. For safety purposes, you should not trust that BMS at all, lithium batteries may burst into flames when mishandled.